# strpos not working for a certain string

Tags: php, strpos

I'm trying to use strpos to find a string inside another string, but for some reason it isn't working for a certain string, even though it's working for the other one. What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php

if (strpos("show me how to dance", "show me")) {
echo "true1";
}
if (strpos("my name is name", "name")) {
echo "true2";
}

?>
```

**Result:**

```
true2
```

**Expected Result:**

```
true1true2
```

Comment: Unpossible!  Your code shows `true2`. Because position `0` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: http://ideone.com/7f88Py **true2**

Comment: @Dagon Sorry, that was a typo. I meant true2. But I expect both true1 and true2.

Comment: okey dokey, read the explanation below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the index of the occurrence in the string (or false if it isn't found). When this index is 0, the condition: `(strpos("show me how to dance", "show me"))` is evaluated as false (because in PHP: `0 == false` is true). To be sure the needle is found (even at index 0) you need to use a strict comparison:

```
if (strpos("show me how to dance", "show me") !== false)
```

Since php 8.0, you can use [`str_contains`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-contains.php) that always returns a boolean:

```
if ( str_contains("show me how to dance", "show me") )
```

Comment: Ahhh...That's kind of weird. Shouldn't that be on by default?

Comment: @frosty: PHP isn't a strongly typed language (consequence type casts are implicit)  , it's sometimes an advantage, and sometimes...

Comment: @frosty no, strpos does not validate that string contains substring, it returns index of first occurrence, its two different tasks

Comment: @Lashane Then is there a function that validate that string contains substring?

Comment: @frosty I'm not sure that php has function just to validate this (position is more universal), anyway preg_match probably better from semantic point of view

Comment: @frosty: not really, `strpos` is the best way, `preg_match` is possible but overkill here. (except if you want to check word boundaries).